# Increment Column Values In Sqlite Using Parameters

Tags: android, sqlite

I am building an app that needs to increment values on an sqlite db after fetching from a remote MySQL database. The code i am using does not do this, instead  it turns the existing value to null. Where am i missing this?..below is the code

```
  database.execSQL("UPDATE bens SET amount=amount + " + avls.get(i).amount + " WHERE wallet_id='" + avls.get(i).wallet_id + "' ");
```

It is not updating..

Comment: What happens if you give the amount table a not null constraint on creation?  I assume avls.get(i).amount returns an int and not Integer as well?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the equivalent `UPDATE mydata SET _amount = _amount +  100 WHERE _id = 1` works, 
but that `UPDATE mydata SET _amount = _amount +  NULL WHERE _id = 1`
works but sets the column to NULL.

The most likely cause is that **`alvs.get(i).amount`** is null or being interpreted as NULL, assuming that the issue is ***instead it turns the existing value to null*** as opposed to the issue being ***It is not updating..***

---

Perhaps try changing

`database.execSQL("UPDATE bens SET amount=amount + " + avls.get(i).amount + " WHERE wallet_id='" + avls.get(i).wallet_id + "' ");`

to

`database.execSQL("UPDATE bens SET amount=amount + 100" + " WHERE wallet_id='" + avls.get(i).wallet_id + "' ");`

To see if that works, if so then move forward from that.

---

Perhaps use the following so that you can see what the actual SQL being used is :-

```
String sql = "UPDATE bens SET amount=amount + " + avls.get(i).amount + " WHERE wallet_id='" + avls.get(i).wallet_id + "' ";
Log.d("UPDATE_SQL",sql);
database.exeSQL(sql);
```